# .NET Core 8, how can I add properties to user account that contains multiple values?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I'm slowly learning .NET Core 8, and I'm using Identity with individual user accounts. I've recently learned how to add custom properties to the user account such as `FirstName` and `LastName`.

I would like to add a property called departments, however, each user may belong to several departments and so the `AspNetUsers` database table structure will not do. Ideally, I would have a separate table for departements (`Deptid, DeptName`) and another table for users in those departements (`userId, DeptId`) that can have multiple entries.

I know how to create such tables manually using SQL Server Management Studio and how to write the queries, but I am wondering if there is a way to add this with migrations and also have the usermanger return a list of departments for the user.

Can someone point me in the right direction. I'm not exactly sure what to even search for.

I am looking for information on this topic.

Comment: It is called [many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many) relationship.